# How to update TeamCity Agents to the latest fastlane tools gem

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, deployment, teamcity

I am currently using TeamCity 9.0.3 running on a Mac Mini.  Right now the duties of this build server are to compile my iOS project on each commit and run unit/ui tests.  When that is all complete, I am using [fastlane](https://github.com/KrauseFx/fastlane) by KrauseFx to send my beta testers updates.

My problem presently is that it seems like the JVM for my TeamCity agent does not get its fastlane gem updated when I update fastlane using "sudo gem update fastlane" on the Mac Mini command line.  Here are the messages I get when a build runs:

```
[09:54:06] [32m#######################################################################[0m
[09:54:06] [32m# sigh 0.5.1 is available. You are on 0.4.10. [0m
[09:54:06] [32m# It is recommended to use the latest version. [0m
[09:54:06] [32m# Update using 'sudo gem update sigh'. [0m
[09:54:06] [32m# To see what's new, open https://github.com/KrauseFx/sigh/releases. [0m
[09:54:06] [32m####################################################################### [0m
```

And

```
[09:55:11] [32m####################################################################### [0m
[09:55:11] [32m# fastlane 1.2.2 is available. You are on 0.12.4. [0m
[09:55:11] [32m# It is recommended to use the latest version. [0m
[09:55:11] [32m# Update using 'sudo gem update fastlane'. [0m
[09:55:11] [32m# To see what's new, open https://github.com/KrauseFx/fastlane/releases. [0m
[09:55:11] [32m####################################################################### [0m
```

What's the best way to accomplish this on a regular basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output `sudo gem update [tool]` is only correct if you install gems locally as `sudo` user. This is **not** the recommended way of installing gems, but makes things easier if you don't care about your Ruby environment.

It really depends on how you manage your gems, but if you commited a `Gemfile.lock` into version control, the version number is stored there. To update, you'll need to use `bundle update`, which will update all dependencies.

Comment: Ah thanks!  I created a Gemfile for fastlane and uploaded it to my git repository and changed one of my TeamCity steps to do bundle install --deployment.  Worked liked a charm, thanks!

Comment: My TeamCity server appears to update fastlane correctly but have you ever seen this kind of message when trying to run a deploy from fastlane?  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2100:in `check_version_conflict': can't activate mime-types-2.4.3, already activated mime-types-1.25.1 (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: not sure how to run sudo commands through the TeamCity agent.  Doesn't appear to work.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by restarting my build server.  Everything working well!  Thanks again!

Comment: That's great to hear!